# Название военных подразделений

Tags: этимология

Как я понимаю, некоторые из названий военных подразделений имеют нерусское происхождение, например, слово "батальон" - от слова "баталия" или слово "дивизия" (от латинского, если не ошибаюсь, "отряд"). А как быть со словами "полк" (тут, мне кажется, чисто русское слово, потому что сразу приходит на ум "Слово по полку Игореве"), "рота", "взвод"? И, если со "взводом" еще как-то понятно, то "рота" остается загадкой.
Та же ситуация и со званиями. "Солдат", "майор", "лейтенант" - нерусские слова, в то время, как "полковник", "прапорщик", "рядовой" - русские.
Почему такое разное происхождение внутри одной области применения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все очень просто.
Любое слово возникает в момент, когда возникает в нем нужда, т.е. когда рождается понятие, этим словом обозначаемое. Для армии эти слова были во многом субъективно подобраны. 
Появилась первая армия - появились первые слова, обозначающие подразделения. У русских это было слово полк. С появлением регулярной армии понадобились слова для подразделений и званий. Что нашлось в языке - тем воспользовались, чего не было, то подобрали из иностранного, а то и вовсе выдумали - полковник, рота, ротный (от немецкого), ввод (изначально - оружия) и т.д.
С новыми реалиями появлялись слова - по тому же принципу. Батальон пришло из итальянского, как и солдат (не надо возводить к латыни, оставьте это самим итальянцам, для нас это слова итальянские), матрос - из голландского и т.д. Брали, как говорится, что где плохо лежит, причем без какой-либо системы, поэтому все так пестро и получилось.
Но основная масса (особенно в отношении званий) пришла все-таки из немецкого, это понятно, т.к. регулярная армия создавалась при Петре и Павле, а тогда немецкий был в моде во всем, в воинских делах - в первую очередь. И так поступили не только в России, почти во всем мире, вплоть до Китая в армейском языке полно заимствований из немецкого. Интересно, что сами немцы частично от своих старых званий отказались по разным причинам и постоянно придумывали новые. Особенно с конца XIX века и до середины XX.

Answer (score 1):

Военные всегда были маргинальной субкультурой (здесь слово "маргинальный" использовано в значении заимствования). Поэтому в их жаргоне всегда хватало "иноязычных" терминов (рота, кстати, тоже заимствование). Однако в преднамеренном "отказе от корней" они не замечены. Оттого и русские слова никуда не делись.

Answer (score 1):

Армия ещё такая вещь - постоянно меняется, в зависимости от времени и правителя. Один построит армию по-своему, другой - по-своему; кто какой европейской стране подражает. В то же время русская армия всё-таки остаётся русской; немудрено, что русские термины будут присутствовать. А остальное, я считаю, пришло в те времена, когда Россия под Европу косила. Все морские термины у нас тоже голландские, потому что принципы флота были взяты оттуда. Я думаю, что и с армией похожая история.

Answer (score 0):

> > Почему такое разное происхождение внутри одной области применения?

Это разве исключение? Найдите-ка область, где все термины сплошь латинские. Или только греческие.

Дело в том, что нет у языка начальника... Был бы главный – уж он бы все отрегулировал, зарегламентировал, закрепил законодательно и установил штрафы за нарушения. И не было бы такого безобразия... ))))